# fragment wtih transparent background around cardview - how to dismiss fragment on touch outside?

Tags: android, android-xml

so basically i have my own fragment that shows a view and its a small view, the rest of the background is slightly transparent. it gives the same affect as if a dialog is showing in android.

[image]

i would like the fragment to shutdown when i touch outside of the cardview. my issue i am having is that i tried setting a onclicklistener on the top most xml viewgroup but when i click on "choose value" for example, it still closes the fragment. it should not. only touching the semi-transparent can close the fragment.  here is my xml code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

//this this top most view i made a conclick listener for and close the fragment when called. 

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="#7f000000"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:paddingTop="18dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_heading"
                fontPath="fonts/Medium-Extd.otf"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="0sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/CHOOSE_YOUR_SIZE"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />



            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:listitem="@layout/product_details_size_item_row"
                tools:itemCount="4"
                app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

in kotlin code its just this im calling:

`container.setOnClickListener { closeFragment() }` and it shuts the screen by poping the backstack.  How can i fix it so that ONLY touching the semi-transparent background calls the onclicklistener i just showed ?